# How to override some generators for ScalaCheck to force to (automatically) generate refined types? Non empty lists only, for example

Tags: scala, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I have a quite big structure of case classes and somewhere deep inside this structure I have fields which I want to refine, for example, make lists non-empty. Is it possible to tell ScalaCheck to make those lists non-empty using automatic derivation from [scalacheck-magnolia](https://github.com/mrdziuban/scalacheck-magnolia) project (without providing each field specifically)?
Example:

```scala
import com.mrdziuban.ScalacheckMagnolia.deriveArbitrary
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary
import org.scalacheck.Gen

case class A(b: B, c: C)
case class B(list: List[Long])
case class C(list: List[Long])

// I've tried:
def genNEL[T: Gen]: Gen[List[T]] = Gen.nonEmptyListOf(implicitly[Gen[T]])
implicit val deriveNEL = Arbitrary(genNEL)

implicit val deriveA = implicitly[Arbitrary[A]](deriveArbitrary)
```

But it's didn't worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to be generic, since I'm not familiar with getting automatic derivation for `Arbitrary` with scalacheck-magnolia.  It seems like scalacheck-magnolia is good for deriving an `Arbitrary` for case classes, but maybe not for containers (lists, vectors, arrays, etc.).

If you want to just use plain ScalaCheck, you could just define the implicit `Arbitrary` for `A` yourself.  Doing it by hand is some extra boilerplate, but it has the benefit that you have more control if you want to use different generators for different parts of your data structure.

Here's an example where an `Arbitrary` list of longs is non-empty by default, but is empty for `B`.

```
implicit val listOfLong =
  Arbitrary(Gen.nonEmptyListOf(Arbitrary.arbitrary[Long]))


implicit val arbC = Arbitrary {
  Gen.resultOf(C)
}

implicit val arbB = Arbitrary {
  implicit val listOfLong =
    Arbitrary(Gen.listOf(Arbitrary.arbitrary[Long]))
  Gen.resultOf(B)
}

implicit val arbA = Arbitrary {
  Gen.resultOf(A)
}

property("arbitrary[A]") = {
  Prop.forAll { a: A =>
    a.b.list.size >= 0 && a.c.list.size > 0
  }
}
```